# How to add or remove children under parent array using react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am working on a solution where I have a deep array of parent having child elements

Here is how the array look like

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "id": "1.1",
                "name": "John doe 1.1"
            },
            {
                "id:": "1.2",
                "name:": "John doe 1.2"
            },
            {
                "id": "1.3",
                "name": "John doe 1.3",
                "children": 
                [
                    {
                        "id": "1.3.1",
                        "name": "John doe 1.3.1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "Name": "Apple",
        "children":
        [
            {
                "id": "2.1",
                "name": "Apple 2.1"
            },
            {
                "id:": "1.2",
                "name:": "Apple 1.2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

basically, I have a functionality where I have a table whenever the user clicks on a row I want to add children related to that row,

For example, whenever I click on the row with id 1, I call click function by passing row as an argument, find an index for row and append children under that along with maintaining state, my solution works only for one level nested child, suppose if I want to add children property under children it's not working

Here is the function that I wrote

```
const expandRow = (row) => {
      
    const index = _(this.state.data)
        .thru(function(coll) {
            return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children') || []);
        })
        .flattenDeep()
        .findIndex({ id: row.id });

    console.log(index)


    if (index !== -1) {
        let prevState = [...this.state.data];
        let el = _(prevState)
            .thru(function(coll) {
                return _.union(coll, _.map(coll, 'children') || []);
          })
            .flattenDeep()
            .find({ id: row.id });
        console.log(el)
        el.children = [
            { id: '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5), name: "sfsdfds1", isExpanded:false,parentId:row.id },
            { id: '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5), name: "sfsdfds2",isExpanded:false,parentId:row.id },
        ];


        this.setState({data:[...this.state.data],prevState},()=>{console.log(this.state.data)})
      }
        updateState(row.id, { isExpanded: true });
  };
```

I also want to maintain state along with it so whenever the user adds a new row my component re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need recursive function for this.below is the code I write in VueJs for parent child deep array. please take a look hope it's provide you some idea.
and one more thing my data structure is same as your.

```
    let treeData= {
                    id:1,
                    type: 0,
                    status: 0,
                    parent_id:0,
                    children: [{
                    id:1,
                    type: 0,
                    status: 0,
                    parent_id:1,
                    children:[
                    {
                    id:1,
                    type: 0,
                    status: 0,
                    parent_id:1,
                    }
                    ]
                    }],
                }



ChangeCheckStatus(treedata, item, status) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < treedata.length; i++) {
                        if (treedata[i].id === item.id) {
                            treedata[i].selectAll = status;
                            return;
                        }
                        this.ChangeCheckStatus(treedata[i].children, item, status);
                    }
                }

makeTreeViewThroughCsvData(csvData) {
            const data = this.csvToJSON(csvData)
            this.rows_new = [...this.rows_new, ...data];
            this.rows_new.forEach((_data) => {
                let newNode = {}
                for (const key in _data) {
                    if (_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        newNode[key.trim()] = _data[key]
                    }
                }
                newNode['children'] = []
               
                newNode['status'] = _data.status
                /* eslint-disable */
                newNode = rest
                //variable hold new tree data
                this.treeData.push(newNode)
            })
            this.generateFinalTreeData();
        },
        generateFinalTreeData() {
            const root = []
            const nodeIds = []
            const mapping = {}
            this.treeData.forEach(node => {
                // No parentId means Node
                if (node.parent_id != undefined) {
                    //increment NODE ID only when parent_is is not undefined
                    nodeIds.push(node.id)
                }
                if (node.parent_id == 0 || node.parent_id == 1) return root.push(node);
                // Insert node as child of parent
                let parentKey = mapping[node.parent_id];
                if (typeof parentKey !== "number") {
                    parentKey = this.treeData.findIndex(el => el.id === node.parent_id);
                    mapping[node.parent_id] = parentKey;
                }
                if (!this.treeData[parentKey].children) {
                    return this.treeData[parentKey].children = [node];
                }
                this.treeData[parentKey].children.push(node);
            });
            this.finalTreeData = root
            //vuex commit statement == Redux dispach
            this.$store.commit('setTreeViewData', root);
            this.$store.commit('setMaxNodeId', Math.max(...nodeIds) + 1);
        }
```

Comment: But state wont update properly with this solution ! do you thing while updating state i need to flatten array, update state and again have to convert it in tree structure?

Comment: In my code I'm using vuex for state management. here I copy the state data in local variable before manipulation. once I got things one then I'm updating the complete tree object  in vuex

Comment: I am doing same :)

Comment: I'm adding 2 more functions please take a look them too.makeTreeViewThroughCsvData,generateFinalTreeData